# Show html siblings as a table, kind of

Tags: css

I have some HTML:

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="nr">1</div>
    <p>paragraph one one one one one</p>
    <p>paragraph two two two two two two</p>
    <p>paragraph three three three three three</p>
</div>
```

I would like to style the elements like this:

[image: example of what i want to achieve]

So kind of like a table where the .nr `div` is the entire first column, and the paragraphs are all rows of the second column.

Is this possible to do without changing the markup? I have tried the following, but I feel like it isn't pretty.

on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S329D/):

```
.article {

}
.nr {
    font-size: 3em;
}
p {
    position: relative;
    top: -4.2em;
    left: 2em;
}
```

Comment: if you don't want it to be dependent on font-size, use `px` instead of `em`.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your current implementation, IMO its pretty solid. If you *were* to go for an alternative, I'd probably suggest `display:table` per @Danield 's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css tables:

```
.article {
    display: table;
}
.nr {
    font-size: 3em;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/S329D/2/)**